# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, sqljdbc

I used this code to create a connection to SQL Server.

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;" +
        "databaseName=db;user=db;password=pwd";
    Connection con = null;
  try {
     // Establish the connection.
     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        return "true";
  }

  // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

but i got this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed". ClientConnectionId:5975fad5-8f8d-496a-a2bb-bff3a8d1a755

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `con`?  Have you tried calling `con.Open()` or equivalent?

Comment: I'm sorry. i forgot to write the definition of variables.i'll edit the question

Comment: I think there is not `IP` in a connection string

Comment: I just write IP as an example :). assume it is localhost or 127.0.0.1 or any other host

Comment: @MojtabaMahamed I'm sorry. My fault :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this [Microsoft JDBC Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/) post:

- [The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2008/09/09/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption.aspx)

for resolve SSL problems with SQLServer ([specially for android clients](http://ppe.blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsql/archive/2012/10/12/microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-driver-android-os.aspx):JDBC driver can not be used effectively in the Android OS on unfortunately) try to using [jDTS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/):

> ***`jTDS`*** is an open source 100% pure Java (type 4) JDBC 3.0 driver for Microsoft SQL Server (6.5, 7, 2000, 2005, 2008 and 2012)

Comment: You're right. It works for me. But anybody should keep in mind that JTDS 1.3.1 does not work with android so we must use 1.2.8

Comment: I'm successfully using jTDS 1.3.1 on Android, versions 5.0 through 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

```
databaseName=MyDB
```

or

```
database=MyDB
```

?

Try the latter.

Are you on a Windows Machine?
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

Download that and try to talk to your server outside of your code.
The port query tool will show you if its a firewall (or similar) issue, outside of the code.

Comment: I downloaded the code from Microsoft page for Sqljdbc. I can connect to my server via Sql Server Management Studio and there is no problem.