# JDBC driver for SQL server 2014 with jdk 1.6

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL server 2014 with JAVA 6 (version 1.6.0_24). When i try to start my JBOSS Server and server tries to connect to database I get following exception.
I used sqljdbc.jar, sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc41.jar on Jboss Server but none of those seem to work

Any help is kindly appreciated!... thank you

15:31:46,792 INFO [ServerConfigLoader] ServerConfigLoader: loading properties for machine name ending in 'BDB' 15:31:47,399 ERROR [STDERR] Jul 22, 2016 3:31:47 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL WARNING: TDSChannel ( ConnectionID:1 TransactionID:0x0000000000000000) SSL handshake failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate secret 15:31:47,403 WARN [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate secret.)

Comment: Hi Anna, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620869/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure

Comment: At minimum try upgrading to a higher version of Java 6, the last publicly available version is Java 6 update 45 (higher versions are available if you have support contact); I seem to recall something changed in SSL support somewhere around update 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much, that seemed to have worked. I upgraded to jdk 1.7 and that fixed the issue.