# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using SSL

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc, jtds

I'm having problems connecting to SQL databases. Whenever I try to connect to a SQL server I get the following error;

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:.....".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 160 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:.....
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:651)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:708)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:895)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:883)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
    ... 165 more
```

This is using `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Whenever I use the JtDS driver (suggested by eg. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620869/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure)), I'm still not able to connect to the SQL server and I get the following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: DB server closed connection.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2481)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 160 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DB server closed connection.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:852)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:731)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:114)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2368)
    ... 164 more
```

The connection string I use: (using jtds)

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://url.database.windows.net:[PORT];database=name;`

OR when not using jtds..

`jdbc:sqlserver://url.database.windows.net:[PORT];database=name;`

I also have a server that is actually able to run and connect to the database using these configurations. I just keep getting these errors trying to connect to the database locally.

I am running macOS Sierra version 10.21

jtds version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

sqlserver version:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

**I am able to connect to the database using the same configuration AND same laptop on a different network. It is only on my network at home that I get this error**

Comment: For jTDS, the default is `ssl=off`. Try adding `ssl=request` or `ssl=require` to the end of your jTDS connection URL. (jTDS has a [long-standing issue with SSL connections](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/725/) and neither of those worked for me, but I didn't go downloading patched JAR files or anything like that.) As for Microsoft's JDBC driver, it is not officially supported on Mac OS (as per "System Requirements listed [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)).

Comment: I will try this tomorrow . Thanks.

Comment: Also, since it appears that you are trying to connect to Azure, you should make sure that you are using a current version of the Microsoft JDBC driver. FWIW, I just tried the latest version of the Microsoft driver in "sqljdbc_6.0.7507.100_enu.tar.gz" and it worked just fine over SSL from a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS box. Even though macOS may not be officially supported, a web search uncovered a number of claims that the Microsoft JDBC can (or at least *used to*) work on Macs, e.g., [here](http://razorsql.com/articles/sql_server_mac.html).

Comment: @GordThompson i was fine a few days ago but this error started to randomly appear.. already tried reinstalling java etc. But no success... i will try a different network soon as I think it might be related to that. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Do you have a SQL server installed in a VM on your mac laptop or is it a different database server on your home network? Are you accessing the database across a VPN? Can you give any details on the network? What version of SQL server are you using? What version of java? I use the official microsoft driver with SQL Server 2008,2012, and I have similar errors, but it was probably not the same scenario. Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @J-Bar java version: 1.8.0_10; SQL Server; Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: If the only variable is the network, then that is probably where the problem is. I had this same error happen when the windows server went to install updates.

Comment: But how does it even matter what network I am working on? I have no clue where to begin looking :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that when your laptop is on a "different network" that it is then inside the firewall that is also protecting the database servers you are connecting to. Hence, there is no problem making the database connections for this case.

Your "network at home" I presume is outside of the firewall protecting the database servers that you are trying to connect to. Hence, your database connection attempts for this case are being ignored due to the firewall protection.

If these assumptions are correct, you will need to contact the network administrator of the "different network" to gain access through the firewall from your home network.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this later today and let you know if it worked, thanks!

Comment: Not actually what fixed my problem, it magicly went away after some time. Though, must be useful for anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Beware, problems that magically disappear without explanation can often reoccur.

Answer (score 4):

Please make your string `url` like below and add `sqljdbc42.jar` in your project

```
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" +serverName + ":1433;DatabaseName=" + dbName +";

encrypt = true;

trustServerCertificate=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163324

The solution is:

- open terminal
- run `scutil --getHostName`
- if hostname is not set or contains .local, run `sudo scutil --set HostName "<YOUR HOSTNAME HERE>"`

Answer (score 1):

This exception also be present when your SQLJDBC driver jar is old .. for example if your SQL server is latest 2018 or 2019 then if you use old JDBC jar file like sqljdbc4.0 then you will get this exception

**Solution for this would be** take latest jar file to support 2018 or 2020 version .. i have used below jar file **mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar** to solve the issue. so look into this way as well

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms","");
```

Answer (score 0):

for DataGrip

go to advanced and set `trustServerCertificate` to `true`

[image]