# SQL Server did not return a response error

Tags: mysql, clojure

When I try accessing Azure SQL server I get the following error. The connection looks fine via DBeaver though.

I recently updated my mac OS to Mojave, would that have caused any driver incompatibility? Any thoughts on how to solve this issue? This is really bugging me, any help will be much appreciated!

I am trying to access a table in Azure My SQL, and the code is in clojure hence the error stack trace as below:

```
    #error {
 :cause SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:98906d8f-3e0c-424e-8145-04636958e14b
 :via
 [{:type com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
   :message SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:98906d8f-3e0c-424e-8145-04636958e14b
   :at [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection terminate SQLServerConnection.java 1667]}]
 :trace
 [[com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection terminate SQLServerConnection.java 1667]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection terminate SQLServerConnection.java 1654]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader readPacket IOBuffer.java 4844]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand startResponse IOBuffer.java 6154]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand startResponse IOBuffer.java 6106]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection sendLogon SQLServerConnection.java 2907]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection logon SQLServerConnection.java 2234]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection access$000 SQLServerConnection.java 41]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand doExecute SQLServerConnection.java 2220]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand execute IOBuffer.java 5696]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection executeCommand SQLServerConnection.java 1715]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection connectHelper SQLServerConnection.java 1326]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection login SQLServerConnection.java 991]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection connect SQLServerConnection.java 827]
  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver connect SQLServerDriver.java 1012]
  [java.sql.DriverManager getConnection DriverManager.java 664]
  [java.sql.DriverManager getConnection DriverManager.java 208]
  [clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection invokeStatic jdbc.clj 272]
  [clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection invoke jdbc.clj 193]
  [korma.db$do_query invokeStatic db.clj 286]
  [korma.db$do_query invoke db.clj 283]
  [korma.core$exec invokeStatic core.clj 498]
  [korma.core$exec invoke core.clj 477]
  [swbimodel.provider_info$get_for_pid invokeStatic provider_info.clj 22]
  [swbimodel.provider_info$get_for_pid invoke provider_info.clj 18]
  [genki.utils$sql_app_status_check invokeStatic utils.clj 159]
  [genki.utils$sql_app_status_check invoke utils.clj 157]
  [user$eval40383 invokeStatic form-init5576567307560081321.clj 1]
  [user$eval40383 invoke form-init5576567307560081321.clj 1]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler eval Compiler.java 6927]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler eval Compiler.java 6890]
  [clojure.core$eval invokeStatic core.clj 3105]
  [clojure.core$eval invoke core.clj 3101]
  [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408$fn__7411 invoke main.clj 240]
  [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408 invoke main.clj 240]
  [clojure.main$repl$fn__7417 invoke main.clj 258]
  [clojure.main$repl invokeStatic main.clj 258]
  [clojure.main$repl doInvoke main.clj 174]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke RestFn.java 1523]
  [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__39798 invoke interruptible_eval.clj 87]
  [clojure.lang.AFn applyToHelper AFn.java 152]
  [clojure.lang.AFn applyTo AFn.java 144]
  [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic core.clj 646]
  [clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_ invokeStatic core.clj 1881]
  [clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_ doInvoke core.clj 1881]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke RestFn.java 425]
  [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate invokeStatic interruptible_eval.clj 85]
  [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate invoke interruptible_eval.clj 55]
  [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__39843$fn__39846 invoke interruptible_eval.clj 222]
  [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__39838 invoke interruptible_eval.clj 190]
  [clojure.lang.AFn run AFn.java 22]
  [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor runWorker ThreadPoolExecutor.java 1149]
  [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker run ThreadPoolExecutor.java 624]
  [java.lang.Thread run Thread.java 748]]}
```

Clojure code where am referencing sql:

```
(defn get-for-pid [pid]
  (let [query (-> (select* sql-table)
      (where (= :PID pid)))]
      (select query)))

(defn status-check [pid]
  (let [sqlstatus (vec (get-for-pid pid))]
    (if (empty? sqlstatus) false 
      (if (contains? (first sqlstatus) :Status) 
        (get-in (first sqlstatus) [:Status]) false))))
```

Comment: What's the code?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers I've added it in the post

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that during your OS upgrade you got a new set of firewall rules and DBeaver is authorized but other Java programs are not allowed to use the port required for the connection?

Comment: Could be, thanks. Will check on how to resolve it if thats the case.

Answer (score 0):

Update: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677960/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-ssl) helped me solve it. I just set the hostname by running:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName "YOUR HOSTNAME HERE"
```