# Problem with: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException in java application connecting to MSSQL database

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

**I’ve been receiving the following error:**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:be8d9e1d-fff7-4310-ae77-03394c83f86b".
```

**(More of the error at bottom of post)
When trying to connect to a MSSQL database.**

**I’m using the following connection string:**

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.190:1433;databaseName=myDatabase;user=validUser;password=validPassword;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;sslProtocol=TLSv1;
```

**I’ve tried variations of the connection string, essentially changing and omitting:**

```
encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;sslProtocol=TLSv1;
```

**I’ve tried different versions of the driver from:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

**all with the same results.**

- It is important to note that on some PC’s the application connects
  and works as expected but I have so far found no real differences
  between the PC’s or user accounts, no pattern really.
- I’ve tried different versions of the JDK and different JRE’s, all
  give the same results.
  **UPDATE: I have since found JRE 1.8.0_152 works in all my test cases**
- I’ve tried looking at logs on the servers and there are no entries in
  the SQL logs.
- If I try a connection string with the wrong credentials, the error is
  exactly the same.
- I’ve setup a test server and database, this works fine, as does one I
  setup in a Virtual Machine.
- I can connect to said database using Navicat for example and have
  another application, writing in Visual Basic.Net that connects fine,
  so it would see that it is just something with this driver or java,
  but as I say, it does work on some PC’s and not others and of course
  works as expected in my test environment.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**I’ve not provided any code, as I can replicate the exact same results using the example code provided here:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java?view=sql-server-2017

**More detail on error:**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:be8d9e1d-fff7-4310-ae77-03394c83f86b".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2670)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1837)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2257)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1921)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1762)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:623)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at database.DataBase.openConnection(DataBase.java:122)
    at jambuddylite.jblCoord.readSimex(jblCoord.java:387)
    at jambuddylite.jblCoord$2.run(jblCoord.java:314)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:be8d9e1d-fff7-4310-ae77-03394c83f86b
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:780)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:836)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1009)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:997)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1767)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: We’re you able to solve this ? If so could you please explain the fix

Comment: Meiyappan Kannappa I no longer update this project but did find the only solution for me was to have JRE 1.8.0_152 on the target machines, anything newer gave the error as above.

Answer (score -1):

check the port is open or not using on cmd or terminal

```
telnet 192.168.100.190 1433
```

and check the database name and credentials

and firewall there is some thing in firewall i think

and take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677960/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-ssl) may help you

Comment: fathy elshemy this was not the problem, the issue remains unresolved with all other JRE's that I have tried with exception to JRE 1.8.0_152

Comment: @plisken I don't talk about JRE but about connectivity with your sql server this exception happened to me more than once and every time there was something in connectivity so my steps is about check connectivity with sql server and check you configurations too bro.