# How to set a null table-type parameter when calling a stored procedure with JTDS

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, jtds

How to set the parameter `@p_ItemShelfList [file].[udtt_ItemShelfPair] READONLY`
correctly as with

```
cs.setNull(3, Types.NULL);
```

When I try that I get a

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with udtt_ItemShelfPair

```
           protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (DBcard.trim().equals("") || DBshelf.trim().equals(""))
            z = getString(R.string.Invalid_Credentials);
        else {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = getString(R.string.Forbindelses_fejl);
                } else {
                    String itemcard = DBcard;
                    {
                        if (itemcard.substring(0, 1).startsWith("K")) {
                            itemcard = itemcard.substring(1);
                        } else {
                            itemcard = itemcard;//.substring(0));
                        }
                    }
                    String itemshelf = DBshelf;
                    {
                        if (itemshelf.substring(0, 1).startsWith("R")) {
                            itemshelf = "" + itemshelf.substring(1);
                        } else {
                            itemshelf = "" + itemshelf;//.substring(0));
                        }
                    }
                    String doerTicket;
                    doerTicket = setingPreferences.getString("doerTicket", "");
                    String sql = "{call dbo.usp_assignPartToShelf(?,?,?,?,?)}";
                    try (CallableStatement s = con.prepareCall(sql)) {
                        s.setString(1, itemshelf);
                        s.setString(2, itemcard);

                        SQLServerDataTable dt = new SQLServerDataTable();
                        dt.addColumnMetadata("ItemNumber", Types.INTEGER);
                        dt.addColumnMetadata("ShelfNumber", Types.INTEGER);
                        ((SQLServerCallableStatement) s).setStructured(3, "dbo.udtt_ItemShelfPair", dt);

                        s.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
                        s.setString(5, doerTicket);

                        boolean hasResultSet = s.execute();
                        if (hasResultSet) {
                            try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
                                rs.next();
                                System.out.printf("ResultSet data: %s%n", rs.getString(1));
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.printf("Output parameter data: %d%n", s.getInt(4));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = getString(R.string.Exceptions) + "L2)";
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", ex);
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [file].[usp_assignPartToShelf]
    @p_ItemNumber VARCHAR ( 20 ) = NULL
    , @p_ShelfNumber NVARCHAR ( 100 ) = NULL
    , @p_ItemShelfList [file].[udtt_ItemShelfPair] READONLY
    , @p_UpdatedItems INT = 0 OUTPUT
    , @p_DoerTicket VARCHAR ( 200 )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @doerUserID INT
            , @doerCompanyID INT
    EXEC system.usp_validateAuthenticationTicket @p_Ticket = @p_DoerTicket
                                                , @p_UserID = @doerUserID OUTPUT
                                                , @p_CompanyID = @doerCompanyID OUTPUT

    DECLARE @res INT
            , @id INT

    SET @p_UpdatedItems = 0

    IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1
                FROM @p_ItemShelfList ) )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE cur_ISL CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
        FOR SELECT i.ID, ISNULL ( ti.ShelfNumber, '' )AS ShelfNumber
            FROM @p_ItemShelfList AS ti
                INNER JOIN [file].Item AS i ON ( ti.ItemNumber = i.ItemNumber )
                                            AND ( i.Type IN ( 'P', 'N' ) )
            WHERE ( i.Status < 100 ) --100: Reserved

        OPEN cur_ISL

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ISL 
        INTO @id, @p_ShelfNumber

        WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
        BEGIN
            PRINT @id
            EXEC @res = [file].usp_iudPart @p_ID = @id
                                        , @p_ShelfNumber = @p_ShelfNumber
                                        , @p_DoerTicket = @p_DoerTicket
            PRINT @res
            IF ( @res <> 0 )
                BREAK;

            SET @p_UpdatedItems += 1

            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ISL 
            INTO @id, @p_ShelfNumber
        END

        CLOSE cur_ISL;
        DEALLOCATE cur_ISL;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @id = i.ID
        FROM [file].Item AS i 
        WHERE i.Company_ID = @doerCompanyID
            AND i.ItemNumber = @p_ItemNumber
            AND ( i.Type IN ( 'P', 'N' ) )

        IF ( @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 )
        BEGIN
            --RAISERROR ( 'DBException_InvalidPartNumber', 16, 1 )
            RETURN 10
        END

        EXEC @res = [file].usp_iudPart @p_ID = @id
                                    , @p_ShelfNumber = @p_ShelfNumber
                                    , @p_DoerTicket = @p_DoerTicket


        SET @p_UpdatedItems += 1
    END

    RETURN @res 
END
```

conn class

```java
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.util.Log;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
    /**
     * Created by kewin on 07-07-2016.
     */
    public class ConnectionClass {
        Context context;
        private SharedPreferences setingPreferences;
        String ip;
        String classs = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        String db;
        String un;
        String password;
        public ConnectionClass (Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public Connection CONN() {
            setingPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ip = setingPreferences.getString("server", "");
            db = setingPreferences.getString("db", "");
            un = setingPreferences.getString("dbuser", "");
            password = setingPreferences.getString("dbpass", "");
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Connection conn = null;
            String ConnURL = null;
            try {

                Class.forName(classs);
                ConnURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                        + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                        + password + ";";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            }
            return conn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SQL Server does not like receiving a NULL value for a table-type parameter. Even calling the stored procedure from SSMS like this

```sql
EXEC [dbo].[usp_assignPartToShelf] @p_ItemShelfList = NULL
```

throws an error

> Operand type clash: void type is incompatible with udtt_ItemShelfPair

However, it does accept an *empty* table as in the following example that uses "Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server"

```java
String sql = "{call dbo.usp_assignPartToShelf(?,?,?,?,?)}";
try (CallableStatement s = conn.prepareCall(sql)) {
    s.setString(1, "testItemNumber");
    s.setString(2, "testShelfNumber");

    SQLServerDataTable dt = new SQLServerDataTable();
    dt.addColumnMetadata("ItemNumber", Types.INTEGER);
    dt.addColumnMetadata("ShelfNumber", Types.INTEGER);
    ((SQLServerCallableStatement) s).setStructured(3, "dbo.udtt_ItemShelfPair", dt);

    s.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
    s.setString(5, "testDoerTicket");

    boolean hasResultSet = s.execute();
    if (hasResultSet) {
        try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
            rs.next();
            System.out.printf("ResultSet data: %s%n", rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Output parameter data: %d%n", s.getInt(4));
}
```

If you need to stick with jTDS then an alternative approach would be to use a `PreparedStatement` to run a bit of T-SQL with an `EXEC` statement that simply omits `@p_ItemShelfList` from the argument list, like this:

```java
String sql = 
        "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +
        "DECLARE @upd INT; " +
        "EXEC dbo.usp_assignPartToShelf " + 
                "@p_ItemNumber=?, " + 
                "@p_ShelfNumber=?, " + 
                "@p_UpdatedItems=@upd OUTPUT, " + 
                "@p_DoerTicket=?;" +
        "SELECT @upd AS UpdatedItems;";
try (PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    s.setString(1, "testItemNumber");
    s.setString(2, "testShelfNumber");
    s.setString(3, "testDoerTicket");
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();  // above T-SQL always returns at least one ResultSet
    rs.next();
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));  // display something from ResultSet
    if (s.getMoreResults()) {
        System.out.printf(
                "INFO:%n" + 
                "  A second ResultSet was found.%n" + 
                "  The previous ResultSet was returned by the stored procedure.%n" + 
                "  Getting next ResultSet ...%n", 
                "");
        rs = s.getResultSet();
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
    rs.close();
}
```

Comment: when i execute the sp from the sql i do not declare anything to the table just the p_ItemNumber p_ShelfNumber p_DoerTicket. and  SQLServerDataTable and addColumnMetadata is that a jar i need? as it cannot resolve it

Comment: i gets a The executeQuery method must return a result set. on the prepared statement one

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen - Yeah, `PreparedStatement` isn't really equipped to deal with output parameters anyway. I have updated the `CallableStatement` example to work with a stored procedure that may or may not return a `ResultSet`.

Comment: but i still do not have the SQLServerDataTable and addColumnMetadata is that a jar that i am needed?

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen - You need to use the latest version of the SQL Server JDBC driver (version 6.0), which you can download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=11774). For my testing I used `sqljdbc41.jar` from that package.

Comment: normaly i using JTDS 1.2.7 but i gets a  `java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsCallableStatement cannot be cast to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement` 
with the sql jdbc

at ( SQLServerCallableStatement)

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen - This [jTDS feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/feature-requests/63) suggests that it has not yet been updated to work with table-valued parameters. You may need to switch to Microsoft's JDBC driver.

Comment: so thats becuase i using jtds?? so iam needed to change my whole project to make this one work?

Comment: by changin my conn class to the other driver i gets a The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed".  and thats becuase is not compatible with  [android os](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620869/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure)

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen - I added a jTDS alternative approach.