# Java EE RAR5038:Error while creating resource for connection pool by using Secure Sockets Layer

Tags: ssl, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

We have a quite old JEE application. Environment:

- Glassfish 4.1,
- Java 1.7,
- sqljdbc4-4.1.jar.

Recently our IT group has noticed, that the Glassfish log is full of the following message:

> [2018-01-01T22:16:36.811+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [poolmgr.create_resource_error] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=connector-timer-proxy] [timeMillis: 1514841396811] [levelValue: 900] [[
>     RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool PROD_Pool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: **Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.** ClientConnectionId:da60a9c2-aa16-4520-b3f0-99a6ce660af6".]]

Yes, I familiar with this link:
[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/11/30/intermittent-jdbc-connectivity-issue-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption-error-sql-server-returned-an-incomplete-respons/)

but currently we can't update the driver, so I was wondering **if we could just turn off using the SSL somehow** (maybe with some connection parameter or Glassfish setting)? I've didn't find any information so far. It's an intranet application, so security may be not problem.

We explicitly don't use any parameters to turn on the ssl (like 'encrypt', or 
'EncryptionMethod' etc.).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned the parameter `encrypt`, you can try to set it to `false` to turn off SSL.

Example connection url:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=YOUR_DATABASE;encrypt=false";
```

For more information about the different connection parameters have a look at this microsoft page: [Connecting with SSL Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption).

**See also:**

- [Setting the Connection Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties)
- [The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using SSL encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620869/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't solve our problem, but fortunately we managed to convience the company, that the right way is update the old jdbc driver. Thanks!