# I tried to connect to SQL Server 2014 but an error always occurs, how to solve it

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, connection

Note: I included the mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre7 jar file

The error:

> W/System.err: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed". ClientConnectionId:0c66e1a1-9a3a-4554-9137-9868b305b033

the source code:

```
public void click (View view)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                Connection con;
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP:port;databaseName=DB;user=user;password=password");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}).start();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct port?

Comment: What version of Java are you running? If Java 7, see [How to enable TLS 1.2 in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39157422/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18620869/5221149)

Comment: How can I check the java version ?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yes I am using the correct configured port

Answer (score 0):

It looks like server isn't available, now, check it

Comment: The server is running and I tried to connect to it using a desktop application and it worked