# My Android application does not connect to my SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server

I am making an application for User Logging, when executing the emulator I can register users, verifying the users' stock in my **Database**, but when I execute the application on my phone, it does not connect to my **Database**.

This is my connection code to the **Database**:

```
public class ConnectionDB extends AppCompatActivity {

Connection connection;
    private static String ip = "192.168.1.9";  //"192.168.33.1";
    private static String port = "1433";
    private static String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String db = "PHOTOGO";
    private static String user = "mizrahijulio";
    private static String password = "julio1207";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

    //Connection method
    public Connection connectBD(){
         connection=null;
        try {
            //Acces Permition to DB
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policicy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policicy);

            Class.forName(classs).newInstance();
            connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+port+";databaseName="+db+";user="+user+";password="+password+";instance=SQLEXPRESS;");


        }catch(SQLException sq){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sq.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cfe){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cfe.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return connection;
    }

    public Connection CloseConnection() throws SQLException {
try{
        if(connection!=null){
             connection.close();}
}
        catch(SQLException sq){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sq.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return connection;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620869/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure)

Comment: Please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is local, Your phone and your server computer must be connected to the same network. May be that is the problem, if your phone is connected to SIM network or to any other network which is not same as server computer network and you try to access it, it will not. When talking about your Emulator, it is obviously connected to the server network, hence it works.

Try it, may be that's the issue.

Comment: So, what options do I have to be able to connect my phone to the SQL SERVER when they are not connected to the same network?

Comment: Well first try on the same network. On the same LAN using wifi for Android device. Which ip did you use on emulator?

Comment: Connect your device and server computer to the same network and try if its working. If it works then at least you are confirmed about the issue.

Comment: My phone does not connect to my sql when they are in the same network, and the IP of my Emulator is : 192.168.234.231

Comment: Did your device work in when they both are in the same network?

Comment: yes,now i chage the ip address ad it working, but how a i can make it work in differents network?

Comment: You can make it work in other networks by making your server IP as public so that all the network can access it. One more thing, Please accept this answer and upvote it so that others can know about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have wifi and your computer and real device (mobile) is connected to the same wifi you can use [**NGROK**](https://ngrok.com/download) software tool to run and debug your app in your real device.

Run the ngrok.exe and type **ngrok http 80**,  it will give you an address like the below image.

[image: Click]

Just use the url in your app where you use your ip address. 
It is best to use.