# driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy, sqlconnection, katalon-studio

I am trying to connect to my companies Microsoft sql via my groovy code. Using this code:

```
String conn= "jdbc:sqlserver://;servername="+url+";databaseName=central;user=***qa***;password=***mypassword***;"
    def sqlConnection = Sql.newInstance(conn,username,password,"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```

This results with the error:

> mgroovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: connection
>   for class: sqlKeyWords.checking[0;39m [31m    at
>   sqlKeyWords.checking.connectDB(checking.groovy:60)[0;39m [31m at
>   sqlKeyWords.checking.invokeMethod(checking.groovy)[0;39m [31m at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:49)[0;39m
>   [31m  at CreateOrg.run(CreateOrg:47)[0;39m [31m   at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:331)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:322)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:301)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:293)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:227)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)[0;39m
>   [31m  at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)[0;39m [31m    at
>   TempTestCase1555589132729.run(TempTestCase1555589132729.groovy:21)

This error is not so descriptive, therefore here is an error that I found in the debug:

> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by
>   using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption

I later tried this from http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html:

```
def db = [url:'jdbc:sqlserver:'+url+':central', user:username, password:password, driver:'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
```

and this resulted in:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:aaa-sql-qa.database.windows.bbb:dbName

I saw many answers, most of them say to play with the server's firewall, but I am able to connect to the DB via my python code or via the SSMS. Also, I don't have the ability to play with the firewall. I saw to use jTDS in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620869/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure) answer, but I was unable to proceed there with other issues (of course it also didn't connect)

Comment: What does 'SSM' mean?

Comment: I from some reason thought that it means the Sql Server of microsoft, but I now checked and it mean Sql Server Management... I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but when running debug on the line where I connect to debug gave me this error. This occurred to me in automation tool Katalon (which uses groovy)

(Of course b/c it was not working I was trying to use debug exactly there)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

The conn variable is a simple string, so infact you are not sending the url when initializing the newInstance. Instead you send the whole string. try sending just the url.

Comment: Hi Dov. Thanks on your quick response! In the documentation you sent me the function dictates: Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver) and in the example the db.url is 'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB'.  So I tried String conn1= "jdbc:sqlserver:"+url+":<DBname>" and it still didnt work... Also, What is the mem representing?

Comment: @Tiner Please read the [documentation of your driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017) for the syntax of the JDBC url, everything after `jdbc:<dbtype>:` is driver specific.